# How do I find reviews of specific tour operators?

Tags: international-travel, tours

This is one of those questions that I suppose everybody already knows the answer to except me, but where do you look to find reviews of tour operators?  The last trip I took was a disaster; the tour guide ripped everyone off with extra charges.  I later found out this was **not** a well-reviewed company.

I'm not looking for reviews of particular *destinations.*

I live in Germany and would probably use a German tour group but I speak mostly English.

Answer (score 1):

Do an internet search on the name of the company, the kind of tour or even the actual tour you are looking at, the country or part of the country you want to travel and all other details that might be important to you.

Do not search for all at once, add more details when you have seen the first few general reviews.

And do not forget to check the reviews for the age, kind of person and activity level of those that have written them.

You will get other reviews from my parents than from me for the same trip, while my niece will want different things again. Go more with people who have the same kind of expectations as you will have and are in your age range or activity level.
My friend with poor mobility will look at reviews from people her parents age, due to her problems.

If you can get any worth of mouth reviews from people you know or have met, all the better. You can ask what they liked and why they liked it.
Do not be afraid to talk with strangers in a train or a tour group having coffee where you sit to ask which company they travel(ed) with and their experiences.

Comment: I forgot to add that I *already* looked up the company *by name* on the internet -- and yes, it was one company at a time.  I did add the word *reviews* however; should I have not done that?

Comment: Yes, you should have done that but you should have done more. Add the country or area for a second search and the kind of trip for a third.